# How to hide or remove ubuntu 12.10 from ubuntu unity login screen

Tags: login, versions

[image: Ubuntu1210]

How to hide or remove **ubuntu 12.10** from ubuntu unity login screen?

How to change or remove **ubuntu 12.04 LTS text & ubuntu logo** from system details?

**is there any way to replace ubuntu 12.10 with any logo as follows:?**
[image: Ubuntu1210]

Comment: Why are these images from different versions? What version are you actually on?

Comment: i am using ubuntu unity 12.10 32 bit

Comment: It looks like you are making your own distro based on Ubuntu. In fact, I see [EzySqueeze](https://launchpad.net/ezysqueeze) in Launchpad. That's great, but doesn't this become off-topic by definition? To change the login screen, you need to make changes to [Unity Greeter](https://code.launchpad.net/unity-greeter) in several places. For the info in system details, [Gnome Control Center](https://code.launchpad.net/gnome-control-center) reads the info from the system, so that part will take care of itself once you've made the needed changes to the installation and setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ubuntu-tweak` to do this. Install with the following command.

`sudo-apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`

Open Ubuntu Tweak, then navigate to Tweaks->Login Settings. Click the "Unlock" button at the top of the window (you will need to enter your password). Then you can change both the background and the logo separately, using the settings there.

Source: http://www.ubunturoot.com/2010/08/custimize-login-screen-on-ubuntu-gdm2.html (note that the screenshot of Ubuntu Tweak on that page is from an outdated version of the program)

As for the logo in System Details, this is stored as /usr/share/gnome-control-center/ui/UbuntuLogo.png. I don't personally see much benefit in doing so, and in fact wouldn't recommend it in case it messes up something that may use that file, but presumably you could overwrite this file to replace that logo (At your own risk, and I'd definitely recommend making a backup of the file first)